# How to chart for each worksheet using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing vba code for chart for worksheet right after current worksheet

```
Sub InsertChartsAfterWorksheets()
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim myChart As Chart

For Each myWorksheet In Worksheets
Set myChart = Charts.Add
myChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

myChart.Move After:=myWorksheet
Next myWorksheet
End Sub
```

and It goes wrong chart, anything wrong I need to change ???

Comment: What you mean by saying "It goes wrong..."?

Comment: it apear all same charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, read my comment to the question...

I guess you want to add chart (displayed as a Sheet) after each worksheet.

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
For each wsh in wbk.Worksheets
    Set chrt = wbk.Charts.Add(After:=wsh)
    With chrt
        'change some properties of chart
    End With
Next
```

For further information, please see:
[Charts.Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196568%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
[Creating Charts in Excel 2003 Using Visual Basic for Applications Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203725%28v=office.11%29.aspx)